# Can't delete "Layar" app from rooted Samsung 551

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, uninstallation, samsung-galaxy-551

I rooted my Samsung 551 with Android 2.3.6 to delete some useless apps such as Orkut, Midnight Bowling and Layar. In trying to delete the Layar app (from /system/apps) I couldn't find it there and there is no layar.apk file or even another file name with layar's icon. Is there another path where Layar is installed? Should I config something to find its de-installation path?

Comment: Are you using `adb` or a file manager? That's a bit what it sounds like. Using [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to uninstall might be easier since it will give you a nice GUI and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved (at least Layar is not being showed as installed anymore). On [this site](http://mistical.com/2010/09/30/remove-layar-from-samsung-vibrant-or-other-devices/) I found that I could also remove the `/data/app/com.layar.apk` file. I did it and now I have +8MB of free space on my Galaxy.